# Using for loop for user input in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, int

Trying to get user to input 10 values using for loop. the "<" between count and Values is coming up as en error. Why?

```
void UserNums() {
    int Values[10];   //creating array to hold values
    int count; //Loop counter
    cout << "Please enter 10 random numbers!" << endl;


    for (count = 0; count < Values; count++) {
        cout << "Number " << (count + 1) << ":" << endl;
        cin >> Values[count];   
    }
}
```

Comment: `count < Values;` What do you think this does?

Comment: What is `count < Values` supposed to check for? Did you perhaps mean `count < std::extent<decltype(Values)>::value`, or `count < sizeof(Values)/sizeof(Values[0])`, or simply `count < 10` (especially since you don't have any qualms hard-coding the number 10 into the prompt)?

Answer (score 1):

`count < Values` will not work because the variable count is of type int and Values is an array. If you are trying to iterate through each element of your array of size 10, the following statement should work.
`for (count = 0; count < 10; count++)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
    cout << "Number " << (count + 1) << ":" << endl;
    cin >> Values[count];
}
```

It's clear you're trying to loop through each element of your array. `count < Values` will not work, as you're comparing an int to an entire array. Just use the number you specified for the array size, in your `for` loop conditional.

Answer (score 0):

If your project supports c ++ 11, I think the following method is quite good:

```
array<int,10> Values;
cout << "Please enter 10 random numbers!" << endl;

for(int count = 0; count < Values.size() ;count++){
    cout << "Number " << (count + 1) << ":" <<endl;
    cin >> Values[count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing a simple mistake in your code.
the variable Values is an array of integers.
 you should use any value instead of Values or do following changes in your code.

```
void UserNums() {
    int Values[10];   //creating array to hold values
    int count; //Loop counter
    cout << "Please enter 10 random numbers!" << endl;


    for (count = 0; count < Values.size(); count++) {     
        cout << "Number " << (count + 1) << ":" << endl;
        cin >> Values[count];   
    }
}
```

The above code will work fine.

you can also replace for loop with the following code for 10 size of array.

```
for (count = 0; count < 10; count++) {     
            cout << "Number " << (count + 1) << ":" << endl;
            cin >> Values[count];   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Requires C++11

Declare the number of values you need once.

```
constexpr int numValues = 10;
```

If you need a fixed size array use std::array

```
array<int, numValue> Values;   //creating array to hold values
int count = 1; //Loop counter
```

Use the size of the array just in case.

```
cout << "Please enter " << Values.size() << " random numbers!" << endl;
```

Using the new and improved for loop.

```
for (auto & val : Values) {
  cout << "Number << count++ << ": ";
  cin >> val; // real programs usually checks if it is a valid number or a number at all
}
```